# jQuery $. GetJSON and window. Location conflict issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, window.location

I'm having an odd situation where a jQuery `$.getJSON` / `$.ajax call` is being interrupted by a plain JavaScript `window.location = 'http://new.com/'` event.

1. Fire event

   ```
   window.location = 'http://example.com/something-that-takes-a-couple-seconds';
   ```
2. While the above URL is connecting, but before the browser actually redraws anything, make a `$.getJSON` call. In my case, I happen to trigger this by scrolling to the bottom of the page (loads more results).
3. Instead of actually going to `http://example.com/something-that-takes-a-couple-seconds`, instead connect to the JSON URL `http://example.com/ajax/getJSONList.php?params=...` and see the plain text JSON result set.

Anyone have this problem before?

I suppose a simple enough solution is just to block all further javascript execution by any means necessary right after I fire the `window.location` change?

EDIT: You can see the code in action here: http://myscubadives.com/, but it won't be especially fun to wade through.

To reproduce: First, use the Facebook login button in the top right. Sign in to Facebook, and allow my site access. Once the Facebook bit connects, the following line runs: location.replace('/user/facebook'); - I've tried location.replace(), location.href, window.location. Same issue on all.

Now, while '/user/facebook' is connecting, scroll to the bottom of the page very quickly. This will fire the getJSON call. Instead of hitting '/user/facebook', you will be presented with RAW JSON.

I'll try to make an example page with all the other stuff stripped out ASAP, if no one can help me this way.

Comment: There is something else going on here, you should never see the raw JSON in this situation.  Can you post code?

Comment: Added comment with link to offending page and steps to reproduce.

Comment: Nope, tried about 10 times each in Chrome/FF.  What browser?

Comment: Chrome 10 / Linux. Could be Linux specific, I guess. I'll do some more testing. Thanks for your help, I'll clear out any test data that got entered (just so you know).

Comment: It's also possible that part of the problem is that your connection is too fast for you to be able to fire the getJSON before the window.location succeeds.

Comment: Do you actually want the $.getJSON call to execute before the window.location or is this an unwanted side-effect/problem

Comment: The getJSON call, in theory, should be able to run. All it is doing is loading more results. In practice, there is no need. The page should be changing to something else entirely, and the user isn't going to be looking at more results. I have no problem with just blocking javascript execution entirely for the second or two it takes to load the new page, I just found it really odd that the page gets unintentionally redirected to /ajax/getJSONList.php. It feels like getJSON is doing something funky behind the scenes. So, unintended side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, shouldn't changing window.location force the browser to connect and start loading the new page, abandoning the old one with all of its AJAX calls?

Yeah, just checked, changing any property on window.location but hash forces document reload. So I guess browser just drops all the current AJAX calls to load a new document, which would be pretty logical for browser to do.

As to how to fix this, forbid all the AJAX calls after setting window.location.

Comment: Should I just set/check a globally scoped flag, or do you know of a good way to block all JS execution? Like, PHP's sleep() or something? setTimeout() might not work if I recall, I'll check.

Comment: Well, I tried this. In some cases, the getJSON is in progress when the window.location event fires, and this also causes the same condition.

Comment: You can try to hook your getJSON calls to document.ready event. And forbid changing window.location while getJSON is in effect (by setting global flag and clearing in success callback of getJSON, for example).